# What's the best way to create custom grid lines in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, print-design, grids

Is there a way to quickly define a baseline grid on photoshop using the guides tool? For example, if I want to create a 24px vertical rhythm, can I do this quickly on PS?

Comment: Aayush, welcome to UX! However, this question belongs on GraphicDesign.SE, so I'm migrating it there.

Answer (score 6):

Use the Grid, Luke...

Go to `Preferences > Guides, Grid and Slices` and set up the grid you want. Show/hide the grid with Ctl-', and ensure `View > Snap To > Grid` is checked.

Unlike Illustrator and InDesign, you can't make a distinct baseline grid. The above should be enough for most purposes, though.

Comment: You can make a baseline and horizontal grid using [GuideGuide](http://www.cameronmcefee.com/guideguide/)

Comment: Very nice. I hadn't come across GuideGuide before.

Answer (score 0):

In PhotoshopCC+ you can also choose `View > New Guide Layout`